# NextJS/Vercel not serving .pdf file in public folder in production

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have a PDF file in my public folder (next js app), which I'm attaching to an email (sendgrid).

In development, everything is working fine. Also when I run build + run start. So I suppose this has something to do with Vercel. When I check the logs in production (Vercel), I see following error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/assets/Bonus_1.pdf'

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Here's the relevant code:

```
const pathToAttachment1 = path.join("public", "assets", "Bonus_1.pdf")
const attachment1 = fs.readFileSync(pathToAttachment1).toString("base64");
    
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
     to: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "info@test.com" : email,
     from: "test",
     attachments: [
            {
              content: attachment1,
              filename: "Bonus_1.pdf",
              type: "application/pdf",
              disposition: "attachment",
            },
          ],
          templateId: "xxx",
        };
sgMail.send(msg).then(() => {res.status(200).json({ message: "Mail sen!" });
});
```

To check the assets in the public directory I've added following code:

```
const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join("public", "assets"))
console.log("files:", files)
```

The output looks as follows:

```
files: [
  '1.png',
  'Bonus_1.pdf' ]
```

Comment: It may be helpful to post the code you are using to open/read the file.

Comment: I've added some code. Hope it helps?!

Comment: Is this code running in an API route? I just did a quick test, and it looks like your code should be running fine. Unless, the file isn't really there.... Can you read the `assets` dir contents `const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join("public", "assets"))` and output it in the API response?

Comment: Yes, the code is running in an API route. I've checked your code - yes, I can read the assets...the PDF file is listed there, too. Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Can you show the output? Does the filename use the same case? Any whitespaces?

Comment: Please check my edits for the output. No, I don't see whitespaces and I've double-checked the same case...

Comment: @Igor Danchenko: I've also double-checked the deployment in Vercel (static assets) and the file is there (no whitespace, same case). Maybe it has something to do with cache?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253704/discussion-between-igor-danchenko-and-ives-e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially assumed that you are running your code under the `app` dir (and your code worked perfectly fine there in my tests), but I was finally able to replicate your issue under the `pages/api`.

`path.resolve` should resolve your error:

```js
const file = fs
  .readFileSync(path.resolve("public/assets/Bonus_1.pdf"))
  .toString("base64");
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! This solved the error! Can you tell me why? I'm new to node.js and all the methods like `.readFileSync`or `path.resolve` are quite confusing to me..

Answer (score 0):

If the file is contained in the public directory, the path you have provided is wrong. The public folder does not to be included in the resource path.

Taking that into account your path should be: `/assets/Bonus_1.pdf`.

##### Remember

Vercel's deployment file system is **read only**, so any actions that will cause the file to be opened or modified like when using certain methods of the `fs` module, will error when deployed to the cloud.

Comment: The file path you are suggesting to use is applicable to HTTP requests. However, since the OP mentioned sending an email with attachment, chances are the file is accessed through `fs.readFileSync` on the backend and in that case `public/assets/Bonus_1.pdf` should work fine.

Comment: @IgorDanchenko True, maybe I'd suggest OP follows this up with a code example.

Comment: I didn't know, that methods of the fs module can result in errors - I've added some code. Is this the case in my example?